# How to tell when the DevExpress FindPanel is closed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am currently programming in Visual Studio 2010 within VB.NET and am using DevExpress v10.2.

I just started programming with the WinForms XtraGrid FindPanel and so far it works wonders. However I was wondering if there is any way to know when the user closes the FindPanel. Right now if `gridview.OptionsFind.AllowFindPanel` is True and `gridview.OptionsFind.AlwaysVisible` is False then the user is able to click on the `x` and close the FindPanel. Is there anyway to catch this closing? I don't want to stop it just do a couple of things once it is hidden or closed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently DevExpress Gridcontrol doesn't have a separate event for whether the FindPanel is hidden or shown. Instead I used the GridView's [Layout](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_Layouttopic) event and inside checked if the FindPanel was visible or not with: `gridView.IsFindPanelVisible`